# Git merge - commits seem to be missing

Tags: git

I have two branches: `master` and `feature`. They looked a bit like this:

```
--A----B----C----D----E----F----G/master
   \
    \
     1----2----3----4----5/feature
```

Just now, I did the following:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

After correcting merge errors, I now have this:

```
--A----B----C----D----E----F----G/master----H/feature
   \
    \
     1----2----3----4----5
```

In `gitk --all`, H looks like 5. I do NOT see any evidence of commits #1-4 on the  new `feature` branch.

Note: functionally, there isn't a problem. When I `git checkout feature`, it includes the changes in 1-4 but I just can't see it in the branch, which is mystifying.

#### My Question

What is going on here? How can I bring commits 1-4 into the rebased feature branch so everything's nice and clean?

For clarification, what I'd ideally like is something like this:

```
--A----B----C----D----E----F----G/master----1'----2'----3'----4'----5'/feature
   \
    \
     1----2----3----4----5
```

#### Resolution

Doh! Silly me working at 3:30am - the commits WERE copied over but they weren't at the top of the pile. In effect, the master branch looks something like: `G----1'---2'----3'----4'----5'----B----C----D----E----F----G----f‌​eature`. I'm not sure why it's this way, but it may have something to do with an earlier action.

Comment: The expected result of the rebase you performed is inconsistent with the diagram you showed us.  Your 1-5 commits should be on the top of the new `feature` branch.

Comment: If this makes a difference, `1-5` led to three branches, one of which is `feature`. One of those branches is still intact at the end of #5.

Comment: This sounds like a complex mess, which in any case isn't represented well by the diagrams.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure what else I could have done - I thought the diagrams were pretty good.

Comment: No worries, happy that you solved the problem.  But as soon as I saw the diagram, I knew something wrong was going on...git rebase doesn't break at random times :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have no doubt that git works beautifully, I'm just not experienced enough with it. Thanks anyway for your help. :)

Comment: Rebasing (especially --onto) is one of the harder areas of Git, so expect a slight learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the commands you shared, your topology should be as follows:

```
--A----B----C----D----E----F----G/master
                                   \
                                    \
                                     1'---2'---3'---4'---5/feature
```

Can you verify this using `git log` perhaps?

Comment: That's the thing Emil - `gitk --all` goes straight from `master` to `feature` without the 1'-4' in between.

Comment: Don't use `gitk`, just use `git log` and visually see what is there.  If you don't have the expected order, then you likely botched the rebase.

Comment: Doh! Silly me - the commits WERE copied over but they weren't at the top of the pile. In effect, the master branch looked like: `G----1'---2'----3'----4'----5'----H----I----J----K----L----feature`.